# Как полностью удалить все виджеты из окна tkinter в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Каким образом можно полностью удалить все виджеты которые присутствуют в окне `tkinter` на примере данного кода:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Разрушители')
main_lbl = Label(tk, text='Приветствую в "Разрушителях"', fg='red', font='Arial 20')
wellcome_lbl = Label(tk, text='Бродя по лесу ты наткнулся на своего первого противника - '
                              'ВОЛКА \n эти опасные твари никогда не отступают , так что В БОЙ!!!!!', 
                     fg='black', font='Arial 20')
next_btn=Button(tk, text='Далее', width=30, height=5, font=20)
def next1(event):
    pass
    #Как сделать что бы кнопка всё удаляла?
next_btn.bind(tk, next1)
main_lbl.pack()
wellcome_lbl.pack()
next_btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6):

при помощи функции `destroy` можно уничтожить объекты. Пример на вашем коде:

```
from tkinter import *


def next_1():
    destroy_object = [welcome_lbl, main_lbl, next_btn]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Разрушители')
main_lbl = Label(tk, text='Приветствую в "Разрушителях"', fg='red', font='Arial 20')
welcome_lbl = Label(tk, text='Бродя по лесу ты наткнулся на своего первого противника - ВОЛКА'
                             '\n эти опасные твари никогда не отступают, так что В БОЙ!!!!!', 
                    fg='black', font='Arial 20')
next_btn = Button(tk, text='Далее', width=30, height=5, font=20, command=next_1)
main_lbl.pack()
welcome_lbl.pack()
next_btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

---

Так же если в дальнейшем будете пользоваться теми виджетами которые хотите *"временно скрыть"* можно вместо `.pack()` использовать`.grid()` и при помощи `winfo.viewable()` скрывать объекты и заново делать видимыми.

Пример

```
from tkinter import *


def next_1():
    destroy_object = [welcome_lbl, main_lbl]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        if object_name.winfo_viewable():
            object_name.grid_remove()
        else:
            object_name.grid()


tk = Tk()
tk.title('Разрушители')
main_lbl = Label(tk, text='Приветствую в "Разрушителях"', fg='red', font='Arial 20')
welcome_lbl = Label(tk, text='Бродя по лесу ты наткнулся на своего первого противника - ВОЛКА'
                             '\n эти опасные твари никогда не отступают, так что В БОЙ!!!!!', 
                    fg='black', font='Arial 20')
next_btn = Button(tk, text='Далее', width=30, height=5, font=20, command=next_1)
main_lbl.grid()
welcome_lbl.grid()
next_btn.grid()
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите сохранить соотношение текста и кнопки, надо использовать фреймы. Тогда текст будет в верхнем фрейме а кнопка в нижнем.
Потом без всяких функций задаём команду кнопке удалить весь первый фрейм, или любую надпись в нём.
Пример.

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Разрушители')
tk.geometry('860x280') # Придётся высчитывать размеры окна
frame1=Frame(tk,width=40,height=220)
frame2=Frame(tk)
frame1.place(x='0',y='0')
frame2.place(x='250',y='150')
# В первый фрейм ставим текст
main_lbl = Label(frame1, text='Приветствую в "Разрушителях"', fg='red', font='Arial 20')
wellcome_lbl = Label(frame1, text='Бродя по лесу ты наткнулся на своего первого противника - '
                          'ВОЛКА \n эти опасные твари никогда не отступают , так что В БОЙ!!!!!', 
                 fg='black', font='Arial 20')
# Во второй фрейм ставим кнопку
next_btn=Button(frame2, text='Далее', width=30, height=5, font=20, command = frame1.destroy)# Кнопка все надписи удалила
# Готово. Можно добавлять ещё тексты
main_lbl.pack()
wellcome_lbl.pack()
next_btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```